# C# Dictionary filtering (LINQ) values and getting the key

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary `fooDictionary<string, MyObject>`.

I am filtering the `fooDictionary` to get only the `MyObject` with a specific value of the property.

```
//(Extension method is a extension method that I made for the lists
//(PS: ExtensionMethod returns only 1x MyObject))
fooDictionary.Values.Where(x=>x.Boo==false).ToList().ExtensionMethod();
```

But I also want to get the keys of the already filtered `MyObject's`. How can I do that?

Comment: not sure what you really wants, can u add some required ouput ?

Comment: `fooDictioanry.Where(x => !x.Value.Boo)`

Comment: `FooDictionary.Where(x => !x.Value.Boo).Select(x => x.Key)`

Comment: What do you mean with "already filtered"?

Comment: @elgonzo ExtensionMethod returns only 1 MyObject

Comment: I do not understand your response. How does it relate to my question?

Comment: fooDictionary.Values.Where(x=>x.Boo==false).ToList().ExtensionMethod();  filters the dictionary values. So I want the keys of that filtered data. ExtensionMethod is a extension method that returns 1x MyObject, after the fooDictionary.Values.Where(x=>x.Boo==false).ToList().ExtensionMethod();  the data is already filtered

Comment: Then separate your code into two lines so you can keep the result of the Select clause: 1st line: `var filteredElements = fooDictionary.Values....Select(...);`. 2nd line: `var myObj = filteredElements.ExtensionMethod()`. This way, you can use the `filteredElements` list to enumerate over all elements selected/filtered by the 1st code line. Nobody forces you to write everything in one code line ;-)

Comment: @elgonzo and how do I get the keys ?

Comment: Sorry, i got slightly confused. The 1st line has of course not a Select clause, but a Where clause + ToList(). My bad. It should be: `var filteredElements = fooDictionary.Values....Where(...).ToList();`.

Comment: Read the documentation for `Where` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) to know what precisely it returns. This should answer your question. If the documentation still leaves you with some question about what `Where` returns, use the debugger and look what the result of `...Where(...).ToList()` (in the filteredElements variable) is...

Comment: @john - I updated my answer, but it is still unclear to me what exactly the purpose of the extension method is.  If it is providing deeper filtering on the collection of objects, it will probably be better to just add the condition into the `Where` clause rather than iterating the list, then iterating again over a reduced list.

Comment: @john - Can you add any additional detail to this question. I see that you posted the exact question a second time, it would be better if you could add some more detail to this question or some comments explaining why the answers here aren't what your looking for and we might be able to provide further help.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of just pulling the values, query the [KeyValuePair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netframework-4.7.1)

```
fooDictionary.Where(x => !x.Value.Boo).ToList();
```

This will give you all the key value pairs where the `MyObject` has a `Boo` value of false.

Note: I changed your line `x.Value.Boo == false` to `!x.Value.Boo` as that is the more common syntax and is (IMHO) easier to read/understand the intent.

**EDIT**

Based on you updating the question to change from dealing with a list to this new `ExtensionMethod` here is an updated answer (I am leaving the rest as is as it answers what the original posted question was).

```
// Note this is assuming you can use the new ValueTuples, if not
// then you can change the return to Tuple<string, MyObject>
public static (string key, MyObject myObject) ExtensionMethod(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, MyObject>> items)
{
    // Do whatever it was you were doing here in the original code
    // except now you are operating on KeyValuePair objects which give
    // you both the object and the key
    foreach(var pair in items)
    {
         if ( YourCondition ) return (pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
}
```

And use it like this

```
(string key, MyObject myObject) = fooDictionary.Where(x => !x.Value.Boo).ExtensionMethod();
```

Comment: You beat me to it.  Deleted mine.

Comment: @pstrjds sorry I forgot to mention something important about the filtering please recheck my question

Comment: @john - so your extension method takes a `List<MyObject>` and then gives you back a single `MyObject` based on some other internal criteria? Is my understanding correct?  Can you at least post some pseudocode for it or show the method signature. You have basically completely changed your question by adding that, so I need to either change or delete my answer.