# C# Dictionary filtering (LINQ) and list extension method filtering values and getting the key

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary `fooDictionary<string, MyObject>`.

I am filtering the `fooDictionary` to get only the MyObject with a specific value of the property.

```
fooDictionary.Values.Where(x=>x.Boo==false).ToList().ExtensionMethod();
```

//(Extension method is a extension method that I made for the lists(for more filtering) (PS: ExtensionMethod returns only 1x MyObject))
But I also want to get the keys of the already filtered MyObject's. How can I do that?

Comment: What's the difference with your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555593/c-sharp-dictionary-filtering-linq-values-and-getting-the-key)? Looks like exact copy paste to me. And both are unclear what are you asking. Show your `ExtensionMethod` to let people understand what are you after.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Dictionary filtering (LINQ) values and getting the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555593/c-sharp-dictionary-filtering-linq-values-and-getting-the-key)

Answer (score 2):

When you operate on the dictionary values with `fooDictionary.Values.Where(...)`, you no longer have access to the keys.

instead change the query to:

```
fooDictionary.Where(x => x.Value.Boo == false).ToList().ExtensionMethod();
```

After the `ToList()` call, this should yield a `List<KeyValuePair<string, MyObject>>` hence maintaining both the key as well as the corresponding value.